# FTP how to delete empty folders (only)

Tags: ftp

I need delete (automatically, recursively) lot of empty directories on server (there are non-empty dirs too). I have FTP access only (no SSH etc.).

Exist some client, which can do this? Preferably for Windows, but Linux may be too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use FileZila (You can download it from https://filezilla-project.org/ )

Log in using your FTP credential and url . You should have the folder structure in the UI of FileZila.

**Alternatively From Command Line :-** 
Where yourdomain.com is your domain or the FTP Server IP Address found in the HELM Control Panel under the FTP Account Details.

```
c:\>ftp yourdomain.com
```

Once you hit Enter it will attempt to connect to the server. If it is successful, you will be prompted for a **Username** and **Password**. Enter the FTP username and password information to login.

```
mdelete folder_name/*
rmdir folder_name
```

This Should do the job

**If you can log on to the server try below**

***Try this for Windows :-***
You can use this utility: [Remove Empty Directories](http://www.jonasjohn.de/lab/red.htm)

Alternatively you can use this one-liner batch file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"
```

One-liner taken from [DownloadSquad](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2008/05/05/automatically-delete-empty-subdirectories-with-one-line-batch-fi/), an excellent site to add to your RSS feeds. :)

**Try this command for Linux:**

```
find . -empty -type d -delete
```

The find command is used to search for files/directories matching a particular search criteria from the specified path, in this case the current directory (hence the .).

The -empty option holds true for any file and directory that is empty.

The -type d option holds true for the file type specified; in this case d stands for the file type directory.

The -delete option is the action to perform, and holds true for all files found in the search.

**I got it to work in two steps, on a server with restricted access, no SFTP, only FTP through commandline.**

Like this :

```
mdelete folder_name/*
rmdir folder_name
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it seems it's little misunderstanding here. `mdelete folder_name/*` delete all files in folder, but I want keep non-empty folders. Only delete empty ones. `rmdir` seems as good way, because throws error when gets non-empty folder as parameter. But `rmdir *` don't work for me (it's because don't accept *, or something else?)

Comment: PS: I tried Filezilla, WinSCP, Total Commander before and didn't find simple (automated) way to delete empty-folders only.

Comment: Try the link see if this help :- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/AIXDownUnder/entry/how_to_remove_empty_directories_rmdir_r5?lang=en